# create a rpm which have rpms and scripts and during installation at least one script should execute

Tags: rpm

something we can do with spec file ...
I have created a rpm but when i am  installing  the rpm .
I need to invoke a script which is a part of that rpm .
May be  pre   or post installation we can invoke the scripts which is a part of rpm .

Comment: In `%post` you can. The files will be on disk already.

Comment: Title could use some work. I thought it was something different than the question.

Comment: I have tried a lot . Can you give a code snippet . i. e example . So when we give rpm command like rpm -Uvh script should be invoke .

Answer (score 0):

As @EtanReisner has mentioned in the RPM spec file under `%post`, you can mention whatever you want to accomplish after the RPM installation is completed. e.g

```
%post
/sbin/service snmpd restart
```

Hope this helps.